# How to embed sigma.js graph container div within bootstrap's responsive grid system

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sigma.js

I'm using *bootstrap* as a main front-end framework for my web site project and [*sigma.js*](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js) as it's graph visualization library.

```
...

<div id="graph-container" style="width: 540px; height: 300px;">
</div>

<script>
    ...

    $(document).ready(function() {
        s = new sigma({ graph: graph, container: 'graph-container' })
    });
</script>
```

What I'm struggling on is to remove those hard-coded graph-container sizes and delegate it's layout to bootstrap's grid system.

However, it just shrinks to nothing when I just simply remove the style attribute.

Is there any way to embed *sigma.js* seamlessly within *bootstrap*'s grid system?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for. I tried to make a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vugeyogumi/1/edit?html,output) with bootstrap classes and it works when u resize the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to delegate the width of sigma to bootstrap with a `width:100%`.

But for height it's harder if you don't want a value in pixel (for %, all parent element must have a relative height).

If you don't want inline code, you can put your style into your css file.